# Get HTML element attribute with phantomJS

Tags: jquery, html, phantomjs, attr

I am trying to get the id of two images on a page loaded by phnatomJS. I am selecting the images using their alt attributes but I can't get it to work. The script just hangs.

```
var url = "https://...";
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status === 'success') {
       var output = page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js', function(){
        page.evaluate(function(){
            var i1 = $('img[alt="This is a versicolor"]').attr("id");
            var i2 = $('img[alt="This is a verginica"]').attr("id");
                return i1+","+i2;
        });
       });
        return output;
        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please, see how you should get data from `page.evaluate`: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I still don't understand where I went wrong?

Comment: So, now that I've answered your question, did you understand what was wrong and how to proceed?

Comment: Yes ! thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return data from `page.evaluate` directly:

```
var output = page.evaluate(function(){
   /// ...
   return i1+","+i2;
});
```